# C# tree node class design

Tags: c#, tree

I'm looking for some advices about how I should organize hierarchical tree node class.

I have a hierarchical tree with some tree-related members, like `Parent`, `Children`, `AddNode()`, `RemoveNode()`, etc. Each node consumes an application-specific data as well. After reading a ton of articles I ended up with two possible designs:

combine tree-related members with node value members in the single tree node class:

```
public class TreeNodeClass {
    // tree-specific members
    public TreeNodeClass Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<TreeNodeClass> Children { get; set; }
    public void AddNode() { }
    public void RemoveNode() { }
    public IEnumerable<TreeNodeClass> Traverse() { }
    <...>
    // value-specific members
    public Type1 ValueSpecificProperty1 { get; set; }
    <...>
    public TypeN ValueSpecificPropertyN { get; set; }
    public void Method1() { }
    <...>
    public void MethodN() { }
}
```

split tree node and node value in separate classes:

1) Tree node class that contains only tree-related members;

2) node value class that contains only value-specific members and reference this object via `Value` member in the node object.

```
public class TreeNodeClass {
    public TreeNodeClass Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<TreeNodeClass> Children { get; set; }
    public TreeNodeValue Value { get; set; }
    public void AddNode() { }
    public void RemoveNode() { }
    public IEnumerable<TreeNodeClass> Traverse() { }
    <...>
}
public class TreeNodeValue {
    public Type1 ValueSpecificProperty1 { get; set; }
    <...>
    public TypeN ValueSpecificPropertyN { get; set; }
    public void Method1() { }
    <...>
    public void MethodN() { }
}
```

Some details of my specific scenario:

1. node value class is supposed to have about 15 lightweight properties (they are of `int`, `byte`, `bool` and `string` types) and 5-10 methods.
2. as of now, node value is not supposed to talk with its tree node, as the result there is no need in node-value cross-references. However, tree node object will talk with node value (via `Value` property in the 2nd design).

I bet that both scenarios are valid (because they are widely used in many articles), so the question is:

1. is any of these designs preferred?
2. if no, then what considerations I should take into account before choosing any?

Comment: There is very little different between two methods.  The second method should be used when a node value contains multiple items.  Not sure why you TreeNodeClass doesn't inherit the Net library TreeNode Class.

Comment: Because: 1) I would have to override `Add`, `Remove`, `Insert` methods. In order to modify the tree I have to perform a lot of things (they are application-specific). 2) this is a framework library, which can be used in applications with and without GUI. Moreover, there might be GUI based on WinForms or WPF (or something else). They have distinct `TreeNode` classes.

Comment: Still the issue is your nodes a single value (1st design) or multiple values (2nd design)?  It looks like your scenario is multiple items (15 lightweight properties) which means you need 2nd design.  Now do you need a special Add, Remove, Insert methods to support your multiple items?

Comment: `Add`, `Remove`, `Insert` methods are used to manage tree itself (add, remove, insert nodes), not values. The question is not about them: should I separate tree node from node value (which is a bunch of properties and methods), or it is good to combine everything in the same class.

Comment: You might be grateful to learn that the plural form of `Child` is `Children`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would separate the concerns. The concern of the tree is *maintaining tree invariants under modification*. The concern of the data in each node is, well, whatever its concern is.

What I would do is make a generic container type `Tree<T>` and make the tree know *nothing* about its value, and the values know *nothing* about the tree they are in.

Now, there are situations in which the tree must know *something* about the values. Suppose for example instead of the n-ary tree you're building here, you are building a weight-balanced binary tree. A weight-balanced binary tree must be able to query nodes to find out how "heavy" they are to produce an acceptable balance. There are a couple ways to do that. One way would be to require `T` to implement some `IWeight` interface. Another would be to require the creator of the tree to provide a `Func<T, double>` delegate that can produce the weight of a `T`. Either way, the tree only knows as much about the node as it needs to in order to do its job: maintaining the tree invariants.

Comment: My tree is not binary, it may have 0..MAX child elements under single node. Regarding `Tree<T>`, do you mean something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/679660/WPF-Tree-Data-Structure ?

Comment: @CryptoGuy: I understand that you are building an n-ary tree. My example of a weighted tree was to indicate that there are some circumstances in which the tree invariants depend on facts about the nodes; they are not necessarily independent. My point was that you should make the dependency, if there is one, as small as possible, and captured in a specific way, like an interface or a delegate.

Comment: @CryptoGuy: As far as the tree in the linked page goes, I have read the first line of code and I already do not like it. Using the C# flavor of the curiously recurring template pattern is not necessary to make a tree data structure.

Comment: Would it be ok, if I implement something like in the link I referenced?

Comment: @CryptoGuy: Yes, absolutely. The ideas in the linked article are pretty good; I disagree with some of the design decisions, but the basic idea is sound. I would start with something simpler and less tied to WPF than the tree described there.

Comment: One of real-life applications of my tree is WPF binding. In fact, I'm working on rewriting my project: http://www.sysadmins.lv/projects/asn1editor/default.aspx to consolidate all ASN decoding and tree management in the class library and reuse it in external applications, for example, in PowerShell.

Comment: @CryptoGuy: Well then, it seems like you've found a library that already does a lot of what you need. I'd use it. I'd also review the code carefully.

Comment: This tool is mine. I wrote it, but the code (related to tree) is ugly and non-reusable. I'm in the process of rewriting it and want to make each pice of code efficient and reusable as much as possible.

Comment: @CryptoGuy: Maybe try posting the code to codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I got the Eric's point and it seems to be valid and I'm working in this direction. Thanks for advice, but there is no need in review, because new code doesn't exist right now and existing code is obviously ugly without review :)